# Minitoc + thesis template + pdflatex

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, minitoc

I added the package minitoc `\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}` to [this template](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/) and did as I read: add `\dominitoc` before `\tableofcontents` and `\minitoc` after a chapter's creation, but it doesn't appear.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) produces a file `<jobname>.mtc?` for each of the chapter-level sectioning commands in the thesis template (here `?` denotes the current chapter-level section). So, if `<jobname>` is `Thesis`,

- `Thesis.mtc1` corresponds to "Declaration of Authorship"
- `Thesis.mtc2` corresponds to "Abstract"
- `Thesis.mtc3` corresponds to "Acknowledgements"
- `Thesis.mtc4` corresponds to "List of Figures"
- `Thesis.mtc5` corresponds to "List of Tables"
- `Thesis.mtc6` corresponds to "Abbreviations"
- `Thesis.mtc7` corresponds to "Physical Constants"
- `Thesis.mtc8` corresponds to "Symbols"
- `Thesis.mtc9` corresponds to "1 Chapter Title Here"
- `Thesis.mtc10` corresponds to "A Appendix Title Here"
- `Thesis.mtc11` corresponds to "Bibliography"

These files are created with a call to `\dominitoc`, which cycles through the chapter-level commands and extracts the relevant ToC entries associated with each chapter. The thesis documentclass `Thesis.cls` defines a command

```
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
  \refstepcounter{dummy}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
```

used throughout to add elements to the ToC at the *chapter*-level. As such, `minitoc` mistakenly mixes up the chapter numbering, as given above in the files generated after issuing `\dominitoc`.

To help `minitoc` in choosing the appropriate `.mtc?` file, we can set the `minitoc` ToC counter, or `mtc`, to the appropriate number before the chapter so that the extraction for the actual `\minitoc` associated with Chapter 1 is used. As such, use

```
\setcounter{mtc}{8}
\input{./Chapters/Chapter1} % Introduction
%...
```

since `mtc` is incremented with `\chapter`.

On a side note, one can see that only `Thesis.mtc9` has a file size greater than 0 bytes, while all others are empty, since they produce no sub-chapter-level ToC entries.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :D It has worked perfectly for me too. I wanted to up-vote you but I don't have enough reputation x.x . Thanks again! :D

Comment: Arf.. I just spent four hours wasting my time looking for answer between my mtc files and other comments, and here it is... So clearly explained, thank you so much!

Comment: I spent many hours trying all the solutions I could find in the Internet, but none was working. Until I found this post. Thanks a lot for your clear and complete explanation! It worked like a charm. In case it's useful for someone else, I'll add that I'm using the standard "book" template and that **my *minitocs* were desynchronised with the chapters**, and that **some chapters were not showing a minitoc at all**.
Just by adding the command `\setcounter{mtc}{X}` before the `\include{}` or `\input{}` of the first chapter, where "X" is the number of entries showing in the TOC before that "includ