# Minitoc is hiding things from me... how to discover them?

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, minitoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minitoc + thesis template + pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36846/minitoc-thesis-template-pdflatex)

I'm using the `minitoc.sty` package for a chapter table of contents but it won't display anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{minitoc}
...
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents 

\Chapter{Bioaerosol deposition}
\label{Chapter4}
\lhead{Chapter 4. \emph{Bioaerosol deposition: Experimental and CFD approaches}} 
\minitoc
```

The normal `toc` is fine but nothing is written for `minitoc`.  However the `*.mtc` files are correct as far as I can see.  What do you think?

My `Thesis.cls` file does this to the `toc` but I don':

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
 \btypeout{Table of Contents}
 \begin{spacing}{1}{
 \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
   \if@twocolumn
     \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
     \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
     \chapter*{\contentsname
       \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
     \@starttoc{toc}
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  \cleardoublepage
  }\end{spacing}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Minitoc thesis template pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36846/minitoc-thesis-template-pdflatex), perhaps it's the same (or similar) issue

Comment: You are awesome!  Thank you!  I checked that link before posting, clearly not thoroughly enough.  :)

Comment: If the other post answered your question, please indicate :)

Comment: Incredible coincidence that the previous poster was using the same *cls file.  How did you know?  Also is there a formal way of linking the two posts together or should this one get deleted?

Comment: I remembered the post as I tried to put an answer together, but Werner's was much better. If you can (and want to) delete your question, then that is an option. Anything else requires moderator attention, which you can get by clicking on the 'flag' link

Comment: @user1134241: So would you consider this a duplicate of [Minitoc thesis template pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36846/5764) then? If so, we will most likely close this question. Also consider up-voting to show your support.

Comment: I have voted to close as a duplicate