# TitleToc + ThesisTemplate

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, minitoc

I am using the following [Thesis template](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-for-cambridge-university-engineering-department-cued-latex-xelatex-and-lualatex-support-v2-dot-1/kgfqybfnqkdf), and would like to have individual tables of contents for each chapter.
Doing this with `\minitoc` seems to require manually changing the minitoc counter for each chapter:

```
\setcounter{mtc}{8}
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
%...
```

The reason for this is described in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36874/293622) here on the forum.

Now, I'd prefer using `\titletoc` rather than `\minitoc`.
The problem I have with titletoc is that if I use it in the usual way for an individual chapter, i.e. if I add

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
%%%%%

%%%%%
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{Section 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2}
```

to the thesis template linked above, then the resulting table of contents will also print section 2, i.e. also sections that do not belong to Chapter 1.  How do I fix this? (This doesn't happen in the regular book class.)